# JQuery append stange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't explain this `.append()` behavior...

```
var listTopic = $.parseJSON(data);
for(i = 0; i < listTopic.length ; i++)
{
     $('#idSelect').append('<option>').append(listTopic[i].name).append('</option>');
}
```

Output:

```
<option></option>
value1
<option></option>
value2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the browser is automatically inserting closing/opening tags because of the partial tags you are inserting.

You could use the following instead:

```
var listTopic = $.parseJSON(data);
for(i = 0; i < listTopic.length ; i++) {
  $('#idSelect').append('<option>' + listTopic[i].name + '</option>');
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use:

```
var listTopic = $.parseJSON(data);
for(i = 0; i < listTopic.length ; i++) {
  $('#idSelect').append($('<option />').text(listTopic[i].name));
}
```

And if you want to set the `value`/text at the same time:

```
var listTopic = $.parseJSON(data);
for(i = 0; i < listTopic.length ; i++) {
  $('#idSelect').append($('<option />').val(listTopic[i].name).text(listTopic[i].name));
}
```