# How to append tds into tableRows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append different `<td>`-elements to corresponding `tr`-elements, but no matter, what I am trying: it does not work :-/  Unfortunately I'm not able to show you an complete jsfiddle, because the whole table stuff is rather complex and depends on a map and stuff like that, but I hope some code snippets are also okay.

Table-Structure (header)

```
var table = createElement('table');
table.className = "table";
table.id = "table";
var header = table.createTHead();
var row = header.insertRow(0);
var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
cell0.innerHTML = "Indicator"
var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = "Current value"
var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
cell2.innerHTML = "High value"
var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
cell3.innerHTML = "Low value"
var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
cell4.innerHTML = "Average";
var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
cell5.innerHTML = "Pic";
tbody = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
```

Then I'm using a for-loop, where the rest of the table is created:

```
//"key" is the description of the "value"
for (var key in values) {
    //...
    //method to calculate the values
    ...
    //append values to tbody
    $(table).find(tbody).append("<tr>");
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+(indicatorValue));
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+(regionValue));
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+(bestValues));
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+(worstValues));
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+(average));
    //append image to a td-element
    var img = "<img src='img/green_circle.png' />";
    if (picIdentifier != 'green')  {
        img = "<img src='img/red_circle.png' />";
    }
    $(table).find(tbody).append( "<td>"+ img +"</td>");
}
```

Using the above code, the table looks like the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwd6na53/2/
As you can see, the `td`-elements in the tbody are not wrapped in the `tr`-element, but the table-rows are empty.
Do you have any tip how to put the `tds` into the `tr`-elements? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm quite sure I got the same probleme here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572307/jquery-append-stange-behavior

Comment: Append the td's to the row, not tbody.

Comment: You're misusing the `.append()` by not placing complete markup in it.  I.e., you're not closing your `<td>` or your `<tr>` tags in most cases.  Have you looked in your web console to examine the resulting markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `for` loop, you need something more like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $(row).append('<td>row ' + i + ', column1</td>');
    $(row).append('<td>row ' + i + ', column2</td>');
    $(row).append('<td>row ' + i + ', column3</td>');
    $('#mytable').find('tbody').append(row);
}
```

Here's a fiddle with a code example:
https://jsfiddle.net/u2enny6o/3/

Note that I include complete tags in the `append()`.

Better yet would be to use the `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` approach you use for the header section.

Comment: Hey @Mark. Your solution is also working for my UseCase. Thanks a lot! Now I'm finally able to use the jQuery TableSorter Plugin :) Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Marc doesn't run well. See this
[jsfiddle fail](https://jsfiddle.net/u2enny6o/).

I think you should create a variable for an element tr. And append this tr to the tbody. For example, see this [jsfiddle success](https://jsfiddle.net/cst72twr/) :

```
var row = '<tr>' + '<td>' + indicatorValue + '</td><td>' + regionValue + '</td>' + '<td>' + bestValues + '</td></tr>';
$('table').find('tbody').append(row);
```

Comment: Your "jsfiddle fail" link appears to show a working version (I'm using Chrome).  What's a failure about it?

Comment: @Marc when I inpect the elements, I see <tr></tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>.

Comment: you were correct.  I thought the jquery `append()` function would return the appended element, but that's not what it was doing.  I updated my answer.